# How can I create a countdown timer for an event series?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

hope somebody can help me with this one.
And before this comes up: I did check Google, other questions and a lot of other places, but still couldn't find a solution for me - total coding noob.

**That's what I'm struggling with**
I have an event series with a few dates.
Now I wanted to display a countdown timer for the first date.
After this countdown reaching 0 I'd like it to start the next countdown for the next date.

Of course there will be future dates as well so I'd like to have a possibility to expand it individually.

I hoped this wouldn't be such a pain in the ... but unfortunately I already spend over 5 hours looking and searching for an already finished solution I could just copy and use. But didn't find anything, that works for me OR that I could understand and use.

So really hoping for help here and please remember - I'm a total noob and have ~ 0.0001% knowledge about coding.

So do you know a solution?
Can you point me to it?
Can you show me how I could do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please add some code examples you already tried?

Comment: I tried a lot of codes and none of them worked so I don't have a specific one which I could share here to be optimized...

Answer (score 0):

Set an array of dates and loop over the array checking if date is in the future, then update countdown timer and break loop. Example

```
<!-- HTML element where to show countdown timer -->
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    // Target dates
    let countdown_dates = [
        'Jan 5, 2021 15:00:00',
        'Apr 1, 2021 15:00:00',
        'Jan 5, 2022 15:00:00',
    ]

    // Currency number of milliseconds - Unix
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Loop dates
    for (i = 0; i < countdown_dates.length; i++) {      
        
        // Target date in Unix
        var countDownDate = new Date( countdown_dates[i] ).getTime();

        // Check is in the future
        if ( countDownDate > now ){

            // Update the count down every 1 second
            var x = setInterval(function() {

                // Find the distance between now and the count down date
                var distance = countDownDate - now;

                // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and secondsa
                var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

            }, 1000);

            // Exit loop as we only want to target next date.
            break;
        }
    };  
</script>
```